# Arrest a Chief Justice of the U.S. Supreme Court?

Tags: united-states, constitution, supreme-court

Does a President have the delegated constitutional power to arrest a chief justice of the USA?

President Abraham Lincoln did, but was persuaded not to issue his warrant by his cabinet members... Was it legal or unconstitutional?

Comment: This might be better suited for Law.SE.

Comment: I've voted to close this question as off-topic, because it belongs in Law. There is a politics question to be had, but as worded it would lead to primarily opinion based answers. Step 1, have you read the US Constitution?

Comment: @DrunkCynic the Constitution doesn't address arresting members of the court, though it does address arresting members of Congress.

Comment: @DavidRice That is why I listed it as step 1.

Comment: @DrunkCynic but why? It wouldn't help in the slightest, especially without also searching through hundreds of years of court cases to see what rulings there have been. I agree that the right place to ask is in Law, but the right thing to do is ask, not research oneself, when the topic is better left to experts.

Comment: @DavidRice [How do I ask a good question...](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), with particular reference to "Search/Research."

Comment: @DrunkCynic yeah, the guidelines say that. But when I look at the top questions on this board (https://politics.stackexchange.com/?tab=month) I mostly see interesting questions that have little to no "research" done in the question. Instead they're questions that lots of other people may have but which are better answered by someone knowledgeable than with a google search (until, of course, the question is asked here and it becomes the top link for google).